# send mail by smtp (gmail sever)

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

```
   using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
```

I run the program and he brings me an error Failed to submit mail .. Here is the code what could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplication:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
{
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    var message = new MailMessage(
        "sender@gmail.com", 
        "recipient@domain.com", 
        "some subject", 
        "mail body"
    );
    client.Send(message);
}
```

Also make sure that you are not behind a proxy and that the computer you are running this program on has access to `smtp.gmail.com` and that port 587 is not blocked by a firewall.

Comment: He does not recognize the using

Comment: the using:using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))

Comment: @Israel, that's because starting from .NET 4.0 the `SmtpClient` class implements `IDisposable`. If you are getting this error it means that you are targeting an older version. If this is the case, you will indeed have to remove the `using` clause.

Comment: so what do i do with the old virsion ?

Comment: @Israel, you remove the `using` clause.

Comment: I do not know what to remove you could write code that will work for me please?

Comment: Can someone please write me what I should write