# Unable to send email using Gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to send email using gmail from my mvc application. I am getting the following exception

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

here is the code for sending email

```
string tn = "EmailVerification.htm";
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(tn);
string templatePath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplates")), fileName);
  System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(EmailFrom, "Email");
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(To));
            mailMessage.Subject = "subject";
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            MailDefinition mailDef = new MailDefinition();
            mailDef.BodyFileName = templatePath;
            mailDef.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailDef.Subject = "mailDefsubject";
            mailDef.From = mailMessage.From.ToString();

            ListDictionary replacements = new ListDictionary();

            replacements.Add("<%FIRSTNAME%>", FirstName);
            replacements.Add("<%USERNAME%>", "asd");
            replacements.Add("<%VERIFICATIONLINK%>", VerificationLink);     
            replacements.Add("<%WEBSITE%>", "http://www.mysite.com");

            MailMessage msgHtml = mailDef.CreateMailMessage(To, replacements, new System.Web.UI.Control());
            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msgHtml.Body, null, "text/html");

            AddLinkedResources(templatePath, ref htmlView);

            mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            Object userState = mailMessage;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myaddress@gmail.com", "1234567");
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtpClient.Port = 587;

            //Attach event handler for async callback
            smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(smtpClient_SendCompleted);
            try
            {               

                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
                EmailStatus = true;
            }
            catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
            {
                EmailStatus = false;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.InnerException);
                EmailStatus = false;

            }
```

in the web.config i have

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="noreply@asd.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587"
                                       userName="asd@gmail.com"
                                       password="asd" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: Check if any Firewall Setting interfering.

Comment: any details about inner exceptions?

Comment: Whats in your MailDefination Class?

Comment: @MMK the maildef class is defined in `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting:

```
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myaddress@gmail.com", "1234567");
```

Also you seem to be subscribing to the [`SendCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted.aspx) event but this event is intended to be used when sending an email asynchronously ([`SendAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h) method), so you could get rid of it. The `Send` method that you are using is blocking.

You may also checkout the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6974160/29407).

Comment: tnx for providing the additional info i was indeed sending the emails asynchronously that line of code got in the way of copy pasting...however i am still getting the exception i have tried turning off the firewall. i have some setting in the config file plz have a look at the updated question

Comment: Try simplifying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974112/send-mail-by-smtp-gmail-sever/6974160#6974160 Does this work? Also please note that there are issues when using the async version in ASP.NET: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6935427/29407

Comment: i have used the simplified version but still the same (inner)exception... i have used this code in my other applications successfully dont know why it's why its troubling... i am using visual studio 2010, windows 7, if that helps

Comment: The code (simplified version) works perfectly fine for me. ASP.NET MVC 3 -> Windows 7.

Comment: i will try re-starting my machine then hopefully it will go away `:)` tnx for your time anyway